# Crystal Report "A date range required here"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

This is a formula that I send to the Crystal Report:

```
string fromdt = dtpfrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string todt = dtpto.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string formular = "{tbl_ItemIssueNote.IsueDate} in  (" + "'" + fromdt + "') to  (" + "'" + todt + "')";
```

This works on developer machine and some client machines, but earlier I used to date format like this:

```
string fromdt = dtpfrom.Value.ToString("yyyy,MM,dd");
```

But this gives this error: [`Failed to retrieve data from the data base`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Prnj.png)

I'm using VS2010, C# and Crystal Report `CRforVS_13_0_5` with run time engine for .NET Framework x64 and x32.

Answer (score 0):

Using google I found this link fro SAP:
http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/errors/12/0/en/html/topic180.html.

Check it out and see if you can spot what is wrong with your way of getting the data from your database.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  for your suggestion,

> yes , the answer is their.my friend found the  root error,**data source driver**.. 
>   I changed **data source driver ,SQL Server Native client 10 to SQL server** on user machines.

now it's work..

> The following link would help to understand about those two data drivers..
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a52ae68-efdd-459c-89e6-4c2d1f4b7906/sql-native-client-vs-sql-server?forum=sqldataaccess

thank you..